# What is compiler? How can I make a simple ruby to javascript compiler?

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex, compiler-construction

### WikiPedia says:

> A compiler is a computer program (or set of programs) that transforms
>   source code written in a programming language (the source language)
>   into another computer language (the target language, often having a
>   binary form known as object code). The most common reason for
>   wanting to transform source code is to create an executable program.

Would this be called a simple `ruby` to `javascript` compiler if I convert some `ruby` code into `javascript` code.

For a simple example consider this ruby code:

```
def hello_world
   return 1
end
```

So in javascript if I modify this code using regex and make it something like:

```
function hello_world()
{
   return 1;
}
```

and run this bit of code:

```
eval(codeString);
```

(I know this is a very small piece of code but I had to give a simple example)

---

## **If I am being too much stupid, can anyone explain what exactly a compiler is and how can I create one?**

Comment: What a compiler is? Exactly what wikipedia says. Where the "compiler" (translation from language A to language B can hardly be done with regex, even tchrist can't) part is in your example? How to create a compiler? Pretty broad...

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler As for your question: if you also `eval` the generated code, it's an interpreter (in your case it would be a ruby interpreter written in javascript). a compiler would write out `codeString` to a file.

Comment: Learn computer science, establish theories, __then__ build a script engine, ___then___ think about building a compiler... My two cents

Comment: http://www.ethoberon.ethz.ch/WirthPubl/CBEAll.pdf seems to be an especially good introduction.

Comment: What if I make my own syntax something like coffeescript. What would that be called and how can I create something like that???

Comment: If you're looking for a transpiler for Ruby to JavaScript, take a look at Opal: http://opalrb.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is a [*transpiler*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler), which is a kind of compiler, yes.
You would certainly not create this with regex replacements though, as it's not always simply a matter of putting some brackets somewhere or adding a keyword. You would *parse* the Ruby source code into something like an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), which expresses what the code is *meant* to do. You'd then compile this meaning back into Javascript code, which may or may not produce code which looks very different from the original Ruby source. That's essentially what a compiler does; typically the target language it compiles to is a lower-level language like machine code or byte code, but it may as well be another high level language like Javascript.

Comment: What if I make my own syntax something like coffeescript. What would that be called and how can I create something like that??? Can I use javascript regex for that??

Comment: That would be a Coffeescript compiler or Coffeescript to Javascript transpiler; what exactly you call it is a matter of personal choice. You'd create it exactly as I described above. The Coffeescript compiler is in fact largely written on Jison, a tool that makes creating parsers simpler. See http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/grammar.html, it's fantastic documentation. I'd suggest you write *some* simple parser by hand to get a feel for it, e.g. a JSON parser is pretty simple to implement.

Comment: What do you mean by writing a JSON parser?? ( I hope you don't mean reading a JSON file in your application ) Can you give me an example?

Comment: Yes, I mean writing a program that can read a JSON string and return a native object/array structure. There are plenty of such implementations in many languages you could look at. I believe that's a good exercise for starting with parsers.

Comment: Thanks but I have done that a million times. Do it everyday! :)

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't mean *call* `JSON.parse('...')`, I mean implement the `JSON.parse` function yourself. That's probably *not* something you do every day.

Comment: I was asking that JSON is written in special syntax, XML is written in special syntax. What if I write something in special syntax. How can I read that syntax from any programming language like javascript.

Comment: Ohh yes but same question how???

Comment: Because what I think is only way and that is regex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60817/discussion-between-faiz-ahmed-and-deceze).

Comment: Nobody is going to explain to you how to write a parser here, that's something University courses are taught on. That's why I'm telling you to look into something simple and existing like a JSON parser. Here's a Rison parser (close relative of JSON) I implemented for fun: https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Rison/blob/master/RisonDecoder.php

Comment: OK thanks for your time! I'll check that tick mark :)